# I can't see my Bitbucket projects on Careers

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs

I can't see my Bitbucket projects through Careers after a successful authorization.

I can see the *StackOverflow Careers* on my *Integrated applications* list on Bitbucket, but the list is empty on Careers. Is there anything I can do?

[image]

Comment: Are the repos on your BitBucket account public?

Comment: @mythz Yes I have public projects as well.

Comment: Hi just had a look and you're account appears to be normal. Maybe it was a temporary outage at BitBucket? Can you try re-adding your repos again. If it still doesn't work can you let me know your public **repo name** so we can check what the API results look like?

Comment: @mythz Same thing. I revoked access from Bitbucket to go through the grant permission again and I see nothing in the list (as in the screenshot).. My public repos can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/lipis

Comment: The problem appears to be with your account on BitBucket, the public API we use is returning a 500 Server Error: https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/users/lipis this is an example of a valid response: https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/users/mythz

Comment: @mythz I will contact the Bitbucket support... thanks :)

Comment: @mythz But since there is an error I think it would be helpful somewhere in the UI of the careers to show that ;)

Comment: yep good idea, I can add this to the TODO list now we have an example of an invalid response :).

Comment: @mythz That was resolved from Bitbucket side.. should I just delete this question?